# Process related to Secure Boot taking a lot of CPU

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uefi, cpu-load

This morning I tried to install VirtualBox. Somewhere during the installation I was given a notice that installation detected UEFI Secure Boot and that I should type a password after reboot to make sure it's not an attack (I don't quite understand that part but it has something to do with Secure Boot and MOK).

After that I typed in password, rebooted the machine but chose **keep booting** in the menu instead of a MOK option. After reboot I have noticed my fans are working more than before and there is this process which always takes around 50% CPU (in top of the list on the image below).

[image: secure boot process taking a lot of cpu]

What would be the safest way to fix this?

Comment: I can't see how these processes and the fan issue may be related to Secure Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Secure Boot from your BIOS and reinstalling VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by following instructions from [this](https://superuser.com/a/1533402/1186344) answer. Process is not showing up anymore.